# Google App Engine Search API Performing Location Based Searches

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geolocation, geocoding, gae-search

I have been going through trying to find the best option on Google App Engine to search a Model by GPS coordinates.  There seem to be a few decent options out there such as GeoModel (which is out of date) but the new Search API seems to be the most current and gives a good bit of functionality.  This of course comes at the possibility of it getting expensive after 1000 searches once this leaves the experimental zone.

I am having trouble going through the docs and creating a coherent full example to be able to use the Search API to search by location and I want to know if anyone has examples they are willing to share or create to help make this process a little more straightforward.  I understand how to create the actual geosearch query but I am unclear as to how to glue that together with the construction and indexing of the document.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any examples that show geo specifically, but the process is very much the same. You can index documents containing `GeoField`s, each of which has a `latitude` and a `longitude`. Then, when you construct your query, you can:

- limit the results by distance from a fixed point by using a query like `distance(my_geo_field, geopoint(41, 65)) < 100`
- sort by distance from a point with a sort expression like `distance(my_geo_field, geopoint(55, -20))`
- calculate expressions based on the distance between points by using a `FieldExpression` like `distance(my_geo_field, geopoint(10, -30))`

They work pretty much like any other field, except you can use the `distance` function in the query and expression languages. If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask here.

Comment: were you able to get geo queries working on the development server? They don't seem to work there...

Comment: @Will Brown, please what is the unit of the "100" in that query expression? Is it in miles, kilometers, meters?